# Microsoft Access Form Timers Sometimes Not Firing

Tags: forms, ms-access, events, timer

I've run into a problem recently where sometimes timers in Microsoft Access forms stop working, having been fine for ages. It seems to be related to some kind of disruption of the host PC where the Access programs are running. In order to get them working again I have to restart the PC.

The scenario affects all currently open instances of Access where there are form timers active (four instances in this case).

Has anyone any ideas of how I might investigate what might be happening on the host PC (running Windows 10) that could break Access form timers?

The problem does make me wonder how Access works with the OS to control its timers.

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by 'host' PC? DB should be split and each user running their own copy of frontend.

Comment: @June7 By host PC, I simply mean where the front end programs are running, as against the network server where the data files reside.

Comment: Something must have changed in your setup - software updates, new PC, etc. I've never needed to use timer events. There is no code for analysis and question really isn't suited to SO. Unlikely answer with solution will be provided here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was down to vendor loaded software causing disruption to the Windows and Office system.